# Changing link colours for a single page

Tags: php, css, templates, hyperlink, colors

I am editing the following website: http://ju-jitsu.co.uk/

I did not set the site up, but have inherited it.

Throughout the website, the basic link colour is PURPLE, and when the mouse hovers, it is red.

And this is fine.

However, on we want to change the colour links on a pages:
http://ju-jitsu.co.uk/upcoming-events/

We want to change that to BLACK text, and then when the mouse hovers over, to be red.

My first thought was to do this by css:
`.page-id-5983 a {
    color: black;
}`

However this hasn't worked. I've tried changing "black" to "#000000", and have tried inserting into the Style.CSS in the main theme and the child... all with no joy.

So now I've tried the PHP route. I have successfully cloned the default page template, and inserted the modified template page name. This has been uploaded and is being accepted as a valid template file for all pages for the attribute side menu.

I am also successfully able go to the Editor, and select the the page template for editing.

My question is this: what code, and inserted where, is needed to override the default link colours?

If PHP is not the route, and I should pursue CSS, any ideas on the code and where it should be inserted?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the style.css file

```
#upcoming_event:hover {
color: #ec0000 !important; /** or whatever hex color code you want **/
}
```

Edit the hyperlink example from:

```
<a href="/upcoming-events">Upcoming Event</a>
```

To (add an id to the hyperlink):

```
<a id="upcoming_event" href="/upcoming-events">Upcoming Event</a>
```

1) The [`!important`] will overwrite the original css setting

2) Using id instead of class will prevent overwriting others under the same class since id is unique.

Comment: Thank you very much. The !important helped supercede the previous inherited rules (wherever they are - I can't find them), and using the .entry function that fixed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your CSS file**

```
table a{
color: #000000;
}
```

**Or**

Add a class to the table for example "events", Then adjust your CSS file:

```
.events a{
color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Sorry to sound like a total noob, but how do I add a class to a table?

Answer (score 0):

The current style contains `.entry a`. This has the same 'weight' as your proposed selector, `.page-id-5983 a`, because both consist of one classname and one element name. This means that whichever comes last overrules the other.

So, the most obvious solution: make a selector that is more specific, for instance:

```
.page-id-5983 .entry a {
}
```

You may need to add other selectors to override specific kinds op links. After all, the purple color is applied to a number of selectors. In the CSS, I find:

```
a, .entry a, .related-title, .carousel-layout2 .carousel-item-title, a .pagelink, .page-numbers {
}
```

So, you may need to change by basically adding `.page-id-5983` to each selector that you want to override.

```
.page-id-5983 a, .page-id-5983 .entry a, 
.page-id-5983 .related-title, 
.page-id-5983 .carousel-layout2 .carousel-item-title, 
.page-id-5983 a .pagelink, .page-id-5983 .page-numbers {
}
```

PS: A CSS preprocessor like SCSS may certainly help you with this!

Comment: Sir! You are a legend! The .entry fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

first of all try giving a class to that table (cause i think that you need to modify only the links inside that specific table), for example `.events-table`

then

```
table.events-table a {
color: #000000;
}

table.events-table a:hover {
color: red;
}
```

To be more sure put them at the end of your stylesheet